# CakePHP use JsHelper in elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

JsHelper cant to use in elements ? I try use it (JsHelper) but not work.
 And one other question: was AjaxHelper deprecate in cakePHP 1.3 ?. I read document but dont see notice, i only see JavascriptHelper was deprecated.

Comment: Both the Javascript and AJAX helpers are deprecated in v1.3.

Check here, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3

"Both the JavascriptHelper and the AjaxHelper are deprecated, and the JsHelper + HtmlHelper should be used in their place."

Comment: this is a very good question. i'm also suffering some confusion over how bringing jQuery into cake 1.3 has changed things.

Answer (score 0):

JsHelper can be used in element. What the error message?
About AjaxHelper, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1358/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

YES, AjaxHelper DID be deprecated, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#xmlhelper-ajaxhelper-and-javascripthelper-removed